# C++ Comparing 2d array index to a function value in conditional statement

Tags: c++

I want to know that can i compare an index of 2d array to a value of function. If it is possible i want to know what is wrong in my condition of if statement.Code is given below :

```
void updateboard()
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 7 ; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0 ; j < 7 ; j++)
        {
            if(myarray[i][0] == get_p1r() && myarray[0][j] == get_p1c())
            {
                myarray[i][j] = {1};
                drawboard();
                cout << "Hello";
                break;
                system("pause");
            } else
            {
                cout << "Bye";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In get_p1r() and get_p1c() i am getting integer values from 0 to 7.
The Program is make a tictactoe game with 7 rows and 7 columns. The main problem is how do i update the index which a player has chosen.
sorry if i did'nt explain it good, English is hard for me.

Here is the Complete Code :

```
class Game{
private:

int myarray[7][7] = {{0}};
int p1r, p1c, p2r, p2c;

public:



void set_p1r(int r1){
        p1r = r1;
    }
    void set_p1c(int c1){
        p1c = c1;
    }
    void set_p2r(int r2){
        p2r = r2;
    }
    void set_p2c(int c2){
        p2c = c2;
    }
    int get_p1r(){
        return p1r;
    }
    int get_p1c(){
        return p1c;
    }
    int get_p2r(){
        return p2r;
    }
    int get_p2c(){
        return p2c;
    }


void drawboard(){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 7 ; i++){
        for(int j = 0 ; j < 7 ; j++){
            cout << myarray[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void playerinput(){
    int p1row, p1col, p2row, p2col;
    cout << "Enter Player 1 Row : ";
    cin >> p1row;
    set_p1r(p1row);
    cout << "Enter Player 1 Column : ";
    cin >> p1col;
    set_p1c(p1col);
    cout << "Enter Player 2 Row : ";
    cin >> p2row;
    set_p2r(p2row);
    cout << "Enter Player 2 Column : ";
    cin >> p2col;
    set_p2c(p2col);
}

void updateboard(){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 7 ; i++){
        for(int j = 0 ; j < 7 ; j++){
            if(myarray[i][0] == get_p1r() && myarray[0][j] == get_p1c()){
                myarray[i][j] = {1};
                drawboard();
                cout << "Hello";
                break;
                system("pause");
            }
            else{
                cout << "Bye";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
};

int main(){
    Game mygame;
    for(;true;){
        system("cls");
        mygame.drawboard();
        mygame.playerinput();
        mygame.updateboard();
        system("pause");
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. It might help to give a [mre] which demonstrates  the observation which makes you think that something is wrong with your code.

Comment: I perceived your indentation as inconsistent and changed it, using the style I prefer (which is not the only one). Feel free to change to a different style, but try to make the `{}` indentation balanced and consistent.

Comment: You can compare the return value of a function to the value of an array element. But you have a couple problems. The line system("pause"); will never be reached and you always break out of the inner loop which means `j` will only be tested when it is 0. It would be better to assign the return values of `get_p1r` and `get_p1c` to variables and step through the code with a debugger.

Comment: If you're asking specifically for this: `myarray[i][0] == get_p1r() && myarray[0][j] == get_p1c()` looks fine to me

Comment: I have posted the complete code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you are asking. You don't need to compare the return values of the functions to the indexes. All you have to do is use the values entered as indexes. Since `updateboard()` is a member of the class, it can access the variables directly. You don't need to call a getter function. Your `updateboard()` function could look like this:

```
void updateboard()
{
    if ( (p1r >= 0) && (p1r < 7) && (p1c >= 0) && (p1c < 7) )
    {
        if ( myarray[p1r][p1c] != 0 )
        {
            cout << "Player 1 Row/Column already used";
            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Player 1 Row/Column is not valid";
        return;
    }
    if ( (p2r >= 0) && (p2r < 7) && (p2c >= 0) && (p2c < 7) )
    {
        if ( myarray[p2r][p2c] != 0 )
        {
            cout << "Player 2 Row/Column already used";
            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Player 2 Row/Column is not valid";
        return;
    }
    myarray[p1r][p1c] = 1;
    myarray[p2r][p2c] = 2;
}
```

Comment: It Works.Thank you, really appreciate your help.